# Image-to-image registration to link the 2 images (RGB AND NIR)

Tags: qgis

I have two images (RGB and NIR) in png format from field and i need to link them together somehow to be able to see the overlapping areas, and cut out the wrong ones. How to do this with QGIS 2.4.0?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

PNG is a not a spatial format, so you would need to convert to a spatial format such as geotiff and georeference the images.

1. To save to a spatial format:

   - right-click image layer > save as... Geotiff
2. To georeference an image:

   - [QGIS tutorial on georeferencing](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/georeferencing_basics.html)